# Is Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment supposed to remove <br> elements?

Tags: c#, antixsslibrary

MS's AntiXSS (v4.2.1) `Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(string)` method is removing `<br>` and `<br />` tags from my input. Is this supposed to happen? Is there a way around it?

It seems to be removing `\n` and `\r` characters too, so I cannot call `Replace()` after the sanitizer has done its job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 4.2.x release was motivated by a security vulnerability detected precisely in the HTML sanitizer. More information about this fact:

- [Microsoft Security Bulletin MS12-007 - Important](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-007)
- [Microsoft Anti-XSS Library Bypass (MS12-007)](http://blog.watchfire.com/wfblog/2012/01/microsoft-anti-xss-library-bypass.html)

However, it seems that besides fixing the vulnerability the sanitizer was changed to be much more aggressive to the point of being almost unusable. There is a reported issue about this fact in WPL CodePlex site ([GetSafeHtmlFragment replacing all html tags](http://wpl.codeplex.com/workitem/17246)).

If your problem is only with `<br>` tag and you want to stick with AntiXSS sanitizer then you can implement an ugly workaround resorting to pre-processing your input an then post-process the result of the sanitizer.

Something like this (code for illustrative purposes only):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "<br>Hello<br/>World!";

    input = EscapeHtmlBr(input);
    var result = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(input);
    result = UnescapeHtmlBr(result);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

const string BrMarker = @"|br|";

private static string UnescapeHtmlBr(string result)
{
    result = result.Replace(BrMarker, "<br />");

    return result;
}

private static string EscapeHtmlBr(string input)
{
    input = input.Replace("<br>", BrMarker);
    input = input.Replace("<br />", BrMarker);
    input = input.Replace("<br/>", BrMarker);

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... that was what I was "hoping" for. However, it looks like the AntiXSS library is basically useless now. I wanted to use it on a WYSIWYG text area... it's cleaning up too much. ;(

Comment: Just to add, it seems if you want the less aggressive functionality, we need to use the `HTMLsantizationLibary.dll` which is part of the AjaxControlToolkit - http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx