# About Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment() remove html tags

Tags: asp.net

I have published an article use `ckeditor`.

The article content is `<p><strong>my first publish</strong></p>`.

In order to avoid xss,So in my aspx page do `Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(content)` .

But the result is `<p>my first publish</p>` .The strong tags removed. How to avoid this?

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I guess you are using [Microsoft's AntiXSS 4.2.1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/)... which is unusable and hasn't been updated since Jan 2012. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383891/is-sanitizer-getsafehtmlfragment-supposed-to-remove-br-elements) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269306/microsoft-antixss-alternative) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612875/i-use-antixss-but-i-still-can-hack-page) may help.

Comment: Thanks!yes .Is Microsoft's AntiXSS 4.2.1